# voting entity reference field

Tags: 7

I have two content types, game and player. Each game can have a number of players assigned to it. I would like to have the capability to give votes to each player in a game. What are some ways to do this? Is there documentation, or blog posts with detailed examples?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to recommend something without more specifics. How are you imagining the way people can vote? Are they voting for their favorite player for that game, and can only vote for one player per game? Do they give "thumbs-up" to as many players as they want? Do they assign X out of 5 stars to a player?

The [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) module is very popular, and has pretty good [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/fivestar).

The [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module is also popular, has a lot of different ways of voting, and there is a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zupMw9IPbpY) showing how to use it.